# Problem with XPS attachment

Tags: 12.04

I received a mail with attachment in XPS which could not be opened. Whenever tried it says Acchieve does not support.

Please guide me how I can view the attachment.

Comment: i think open office 3 can view xps file !!

Answer (score 0):

XPS stands for XML Paper Specification. It’s a document type developed by Microsoft, which serves as a PDF alternative. You can use Evince to view the file. Install Evince from Ubuntu Software Center or from Synaptic.